# using a function to compare integers and find the position where one value is even and the other is odd c++

Tags: function, c++11, conditional-statements

/*
        Description:
        Write a function called digitsOpposite. The function has two integer parameters x and y that are 
        positive and have the same number of digits. It returns the number of positions where one number
        has an even digit and the other has an odd one. For example, if the function was applied to 17345
        and 97813 it would return 2 because the third digits are 3 and 8 and the fourth ones are 4 and 1.
        (In both cases one of these is even and the other is odd.) 
Problem: my code is not printing the desired output. HELP PLEASE!! I am a beginner. Thanks.

*/

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;


    // declare function

        int digitsOpposite(int x, int y){
        int lastV1, lastV2, leftV1, leftV2;
        leftV1 = 0,
        leftV2 = 0;
        lastV1 = 0;
        lastV2 = 0;
        for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--){
            leftV1 += x;    // 17345
            leftV2 += y;    // 97813
            lastV1 += leftV1 % 2;  //5
            lastV2 += leftV2 % 2;  //3
            if((lastV1 == 0)&&( lastV2 != 0))
             {

                break;
                return i;
            }
            else{
                leftV1 += leftV1 / 10; // 1734
                leftV2 += leftV2 / 10; // 9781
            }

        }

    }





    int main(){
        cout <<"The position of the number is: " << digitsOpposite(17345, 97813);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `using namespace std` makes Bjarne Stroustrup cry.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching a closing brace of a non-`void` function without encountering a `return` statement. In other words: `digitsOpposite` is declared to return an `int`, but doesn't actually return anything. `return i;` statement is unreachable (thanks to `break;` right before it).